# Can I use only Entity's id instead of fetching an entity from DB when there is a relationship in an Entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

Lets say I have the following entity defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foods")
public class Food {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "food_id")
    private Long foodId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "food_type_id")
    @NotNull
    private FoodType foodType;
    
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "food_types")
public class FoodType {
    
    public static final Integer PERISHABLE;
    public static final Integer NON_PERISHABLE;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "food_type")
    private Integer foodTypeId;

    private String name;
    
    ...
}
```

Every time when I want to create a `Food` entity and save it to the database, currently code looks like this:

```
Food food = new Food();
FoodType foodType = foodTypeRepository.findById(FoodType.PERISHABLE); // Call to DB to get Entity
food.setFoodType(foodType);
....

foodRepository.save(food);
```

If we consider FoodType to be constant in the DB. Can I use it like this:

```
Food food = new Food();
FoodType foodType = new FoodType();
foodType.setFoodTypeId(FoodType.PERISHABLE); // No Call to DB
food.setFoodType(foodType);
....

foodRepository.save(food);
```

I have tested it and yes I can use it that way, hibernate will save the `Food` entity, but are there any downsides, pitfalls, etc... I am not seeing.

PS. This is just a simple example illustrating the idea, it is part of old legacy project which I cannot modify to remove constant from DB, and use an enum instead.

Comment: „getById(..)“ should return only a Proxy without a DB call if the persistanceprovider supports it. In hibernate it‘s called „getReference(..)“.

Comment: This `foodType.setFoodTypeId()` shouldn't be exposed as a public method, nor should it be called. You could cache food-types to save having to load them every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid extra call to DB you should use:

```java
FoodType foodType = foodTypeRepository.getOne(FoodType.PERISHABLE);
```

under the hood it calls `EntityManager.getReference` *that obtain a reference to an entity without having to load its data* as opposed to the `foodTypeRepository.findById` that lead to call `EntityManager.find` *that obtain an entity along with its data*.

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-get-reference) of the hibernate documentation.

P.S. You can not use:

```java
Food food = new Food();
FoodType foodType = new FoodType();
foodType.setFoodTypeId(FoodType.PERISHABLE);
```

as in this case hibernate consider `foodType` as a *transient* entity (not associated with a [persistence context](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc)) and will try to save it as a new record if you have a proper [cascading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) on your `@ManyToOne` association.

P.S.S. As it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) the method `JpaRepository#getOne(ID)` is deprecated and you should use `JpaRepository#getById(ID)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just a quick question. What do you mean cascading will try to save it. If it has the same id as an existing Id in database, what cascading type will result in saving it?

Comment: Hibernate will try to save the `foodType` as a new one and it leads to the `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` as you already have food type with this id.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fetch the entity associated with `FoodType.PERISHABLE` in order to set the relation on a `Food` entity to it and I'm not aware of any side effects or pitfalls of using `FoodType.PERISHABLE` directly as long it is a valid `FoodType` id.

As others mentioned, you could also use [JpaRepository#getById(ID id)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getById-ID-) and that's probably the more canonical way of addressing this problem:

> T getById(ID id) Returns a reference to the entity with the given
> identifier. Depending on how the JPA persistence provider is
> implemented this is very likely to always return an instance and throw
> an EntityNotFoundException on first access. Some of them will reject
> invalid identifiers immediately.