# Save an attribute in entity mapped with @JoinColumn via fk id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with following reference to another table.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user_created_by")
private User userCreatedBy;
```

Is it possible to persist/set the userCreatedBy via the id?

If I just have the id of user, do I have to call getUserById(Long id) at first?

Another option would be to add following, but I don't think it's best practice (column is double mapped):

```
@Column(name = "id_user_created_by")
private Long idUserCreatedBy;
```

What is best practice for this use case?

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67173987/can-i-use-only-entitys-id-instead-of-fetching-an-entity-from-db-when-there-is-a/).

Comment: @SternK thank you very much, this solved my problem!